# json_decode weird behavior

Tags: php, json

I have this piece of code

```
$value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'allSet', true );

//echo $value prints {"0":{"typ":"","pocet":"1","nazev":"asfdsaf"}}

$neco = '{"0":{"typ":"","pocet":"1","nazev":"asfdsaf"}}';

$neco = json_decode($value, true);
print_r($neco);
```

so it prints nothing and var_dump prints NULL.

But if I try to decode `json_decode($neco);` it prints Array as it should.

Does anybody know what's wrong here, when **$value and $neco** have the same values?

Thank you very much for any help

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your code.Try this

```
$neco = '{"0":{"typ":"","pocet":"1","nazev":"asfdsaf"}}';
$value= json_decode($neco, true);
print_r($value);
```

You tried it like `$neco = json_decode($value, true);`. The json_decode must be `$neco` not `$value` because you are having the json in the variable `$neco` since you are initializing it before doing the decoding. So you have to decode `$neco` and not `$value`.

Comment: $neco is the same as $value, only diference is that in $neco I insert json string manually. In $value is the same string but from wordpress function.

Comment: So check whats in in `$value` by `printr($value);` and see whether its a valid json.

Comment: It is valid json that's the problem. It is complete valid json THE SAME as in the $neco variable, but id doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the json string to decode ie,

```
json_decode($neco, true);
```

Comment: Why the down vote..? I don't see anything wrong with this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
$value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'allSet', true );
```

to

```
$value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'allSet', false );
```

If we set the value to to true,it will return you only single parameter,not array

Comment: This doesn't help either.